# Chrome DevTools - inspect/#devices invert or show wrong colors

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

On this week I got a bug. When I try to inspect pages on my phone (samsung note 8), inspect tool show wrong colors on website preview. Just look on screenshots:

[screenshot from phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkPox.jpg)
Looks normal.

[DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPIKM.jpg)
Strange colors.

Comment: I'm noticing this too now. It appears that some elements are being inverted, while others are not. The reds are becoming blues, and the blues are becoming reds, yet the greens are untouched.

Comment: Issue on Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1187601

Comment: The issue was moved to [issue 1189626](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1189626). It appears a fix has been merged into Chrome Canary and will be included in a future update to Chrome.